# Why QML x,y coordinates are changed when changing value of visible?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a problem on QML.

Made rectangle like this

```
Rectangle {
   id: rect1
   x: 100
   y: 100
   width: 100
   height: 100
   Rectangle {
      id: rect2
      x: 50
      y: 50
      width: 50
      height: 50
   }
}
```

and then Changed visible value of rect1.
but sometimes x,y coordinates are changed to x=0, y=0 of rect2 !!!

when I changed it from visible to opacity, It works correct.

I think it maybe a bug... is it right??
How can I solve it...

Comment: show the full code - how you are changing the visible property etc.

Comment: It maybe bug depending on version of platform and qt. It works well on windows7, ubuntu. I tested it on embeded system. need more tests... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates do not change for me:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
       id: rect1
       x: 100
       y: 100
       width: 100
       height: 100
       color: "red"

       Rectangle {
          id: rect2
          x: 50
          y: 50
          width: 50
          height: 50
          color: "blue"
       }
    }

    Column {
        Text {
            text: "rect1 x/y/width/height: " + rect1.x + " " + rect1.y + " " + rect1.width + " " + rect1.height
        }
        Text {
            text: "rect2 x/y/width/height: " + rect2.x + " " + rect2.y + " " + rect2.width + " " + rect2.height
        }
        Button {
            text: rect1.visible ? "Hide rect1" : "Show rect1"
            onClicked: rect1.visible = !rect1.visible
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use... createComponent or createQmlObject something on rect2, It occur...    I found few minutes ago.

Comment: Maybe it depends on platform and version of qt.
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34963
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30772
something else...
I'll update the question...